# Limit of iterative addition of a mean-preserving spread

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

*Suppose I iteratively add a given mean-preserving spread to a random variable. In the limit, will exactly half the mass be above $0$?*

Formally: Let $X$ be a random variable, and let $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\ldots$ be i.i.d. random variables with strictly positive (but finite) variance and $E[\varepsilon_i\mid X]=0$. Let $F_n$ be the CDF of 
$$
X+\varepsilon_1+\dots+\varepsilon_n.
$$

Must it be the case that $F_n(0)\to \frac{1}{2}$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Are you assuming that the $\varepsilon_n$ have *finite* variance?

Comment: Yes, good point.  Added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $E[\varepsilon_n] = E[E[\varepsilon_n \mid X]] = 0$.  Let $\sigma^2$ denote the variance of $\varepsilon_n$.

Let $Y_n = X + \varepsilon_1 + \dots + \varepsilon_n$.  Note that $\frac{\varepsilon_1 + \dots + \varepsilon_n}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \Rightarrow  N(0,1)$ in distribution, by the central limit theorem, and $\frac{X}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} \to 0$ almost surely.  So by [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem), $\frac{Y_n}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} \Rightarrow N(0, 1)$.  Then $P(Y_n \le 0) = P(\frac{Y_n}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \le 0) \to \Phi(0) = \frac{1}{2}$ where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf.